# getElementByClassName - All Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following script in another question:

```
window.onload=function(){ 
    var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('responsiveExpander'); 
    var Rate = classes[0]; 
    Rate.click(); 
}
```

Problem with this one is, that it only works with the first element it find. In my case I have multiple elements with the same class and would need all to be clicked.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried looping through the classes array-like object?

Comment: well yeah, iterate over them and click them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over `classes`.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('responsiveExpander');

  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    classes[i].click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Danny and Paul (for the correction) - Works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

When you do **document.getElementsByClassName('responsiveExpander')**, its going to return a collection of all elements with the class name 'responsiveExpander' from the document, basically a collection of Nodes.

You would want to loop through the list of nodes and perform your necessary action